# What's difference between git pull and git fetch+rebase

Tags: git

I'm working on a project that uses `GIT` as version control system. In the project's development process, it says that

> Do not use "git pull" since that will cause a merge and create a very messy history over time. Use git fetch and git rebase instead.

Basically I know `git pull` actually does `git fetch + git merge`. And `git rebase` will keep the commit graph clean, because after `git rebase`, the local branch becomes to be at same line as the remote branch.

But I still don't understand why git pull create a very messy history? Could anybody explain that to me?

Comment: http://blog.sourcetreeapp.com/files/2012/08/mergerebase.png  Source : http://blog.sourcetreeapp.com/2012/08/21/merge-or-rebase/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fetch + rebase will create linear history (each commit has ONLY ONE PARENT) like

```
last common commit <- remote commit <- remote commit <- local commit
```

Pull, if there are some changes both in remote branch and in your local will create messy history (commit can have TWO PARENTS - look at "merge commit") like

```
                      remote commit <- remote commit
last common commit <-                                <- merge commit
                      local commit
```

Comment: I'd like to point out that `git pull` has a `--rebase`(`-r`) option which causes it to rebase after fetching instead of merging.

Answer (score 1):

You could check the official documentation between about `git fetch + rebase` and `git pull` [here](http://git-scm.com/documentation). But former is usually the better approach as compared to git pull. git pull fetches the current branch and immediately merges it. (Could be pretty nasty to fix it you get conflicts).

Where as rebase adjust the head of the current branch against the one it is being rebased. Thus you get a linear history.

So, always be rebasing when are working on a setup where more than one developers are contributing to a repository or branch.